# Onelogin SAML toolkit for Javascript

Tags: javascript, mean-stack, saml, onelogin

Is there a Javascript toolkit that Onelogin recommends/created? I'm writing a MEAN application and want to use Onelogin for authentication, but they don't seem to have a toolkit written in Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

There is no javascript toolkit developed by OneLogin.

If you plan to manage it yourself I recomend to take a look at:

- https://github.com/yaronn/xmldom
- https://github.com/yaronn/xpath.js
- https://github.com/yaronn/xml-crypto

For nodejs you should use:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-saml
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/saml2-js

Comment: @Tiffany have you found the answer? I am also looking for onelogin library for MEAN stack